# Widgets are all in one row and I don't want them to be

Tags: tkinter

All the widgets come up in one row? How do I stop this? I need different widgets on different rows. I have looked it up and all the examples are like my code but my code does still not work

```
#Placing widgets
Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 100)
FutureButton.grid(row = 3, column = 2, rowspan = 3)
ResetButton.grid(row = 3, column = 3, rowspan = 2, padx = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well.. You are placing both buttons at `row=3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the widgets come up in one row? How do I stop this?

The answer is "don't put them on the same row". You've explicitly placed `FutureButton` and `ResetButton` on the same row.

Your use of `rowspan` also contributes to the problem. For example, when you place `Label` in row 0 with a rowspan of 100, it's going to center itself in the space used by 100 rows. Since most of the rows are empty they don't appear, but the net effect is that `Label1` ends up centered in the space used by rows 0, 1, and 2. This makes it appear as if they are on the same row.

A simple way to visualize the grid is to put something in every row and column that you use. Since your original code has 100 columns and 4 rows, you could do something like this:

```
for row in range(100):
    for column in range(4):
        f = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque", width=2, height=2)
        f.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
```

When I do the above, I get an image that looks like the following image. Notice that none of the widgets are actually on the same row, it only appears that way in your original code because most of the rows are empty.

[image: screenshot showing 100 rows and 4 columns]

The simplest solution is to put them on the same row, and to *not* use `rowspan`.

```
Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
FutureButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
ResetButton.grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10)
```

Comment: ok thanks mate, this really helped and i got it to work, thanks for taking the time to explain the problem and to show me with code and images. You are a legend